# android crash when open gellary

Tags: android, crash

My application crashes when I open a gallery before the method "onActivityResult"

val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY)

There are no errors in Logcat.

Android 10, 11. The same problem

Comment: `There are no errors in Logcat.` i highly doubt that, are you using logcat correctly ? no way for anyone here to really help without an error log

Comment: Are you sure it crashes? Maybe it is sent in background/minimized like pressing Home button.....When an App crashes a log is filled with informations.

Comment: @emandt Yes, it looks like I press the home button. When I launch the application again, it starts from the start screen

Comment: Does the Gallery opens using that Intent?

Comment: yes, it opens, app "crashes" after choosing the image

Comment: Then post your onActivityResult code as you do something there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem ?